# Extract values from JSON file in Talend

Tags: talend

I have json file like this:

`{"2020-04-28":`
`{`
`"37,N7L2H4,Carry,CHOPA,PLX":` 
`{`
`"inter_results": {`
`"inter_mark": "GITA"`
`,"down": null`
`,"up": null`
`,"wiki": {"included": "false", "options": ["RRR", "SSS","HHH"]`
`}}`
`,"38, N5L2J4, HURT, SERRA, PZT": {`
`"inter_results": {`
`"inter_mark": "MARI"`
`,"down": "250"`
`,"up": "1250"`
`,"wiki": {"included": "true", "options": ["XXX", "YYY"]`
`}}`
`,"39, N4L2H4, HIBA, FILA, PFG": {`
`"inter_results": {`
`"inter_mark": "HILO"`
`,"down": "100"`
`,"up": "250"`
`,"wiki": {"included": "true", "options": ["RTG", "VTH","HJI","JKL"]`
`}}`
`}`
`}`

And i want extract the Values `N7L2H4,N5L2J4,N4L2H4` from this json file using `tFileInputJson` with `jsonPath`.

Comment: what is the criteria for retrieving these values ?

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, thank you for your response. no criteria. Please can you help me. Thanks

Comment: I mean what are you looking for inside the json ? these values you're trying to get, are they alway 2nd in the list of values in the field name? something else ?

Comment: Besides your json is not valid, can you post a complete valid json ? Or at least a subset that is valid, so that I can parse it

Comment: Yes these values always in second position in the list of values in the field name

Comment: I cant post the original because it's private data. thanks for your comprehension.

Comment: Here the json file is valide:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the native components of Talend, this is hard to achieve. You can do it with some java code but it's not elegant.
Here's a solution using json components suite from Talend Exchange which you can download [here](https://exchange.talend.com/#marketplaceproductoverview:marketplace=marketplace%252F1&p=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F1438&pi=marketplace%252F1%252Fproducts%252F1438%252Fitems%252F2720)
[image]

The component `tJSONDocTraverseFields` allows you to list all fields, paths and values of your json.
It gives this output:

```
$.2020-04-28.37,N7L2H4,Carry,CHOPA,PLX.inter_results.inter_mark|4|inter_mark|"GITA"|false|21
$.2020-04-28.37,N7L2H4,Carry,CHOPA,PLX.inter_results.down|4|down|null|false|21
$.2020-04-28.37,N7L2H4,Carry,CHOPA,PLX.inter_results.up|4|up|null|false|21
$.2020-04-28.37,N7L2H4,Carry,CHOPA,PLX.inter_results.wiki.included|5|included|"false"|false|21
$.2020-04-28.37,N7L2H4,Carry,CHOPA,PLX.inter_results.wiki.options[0]|6|options|"RRR"|true|21
$.2020-04-28.37,N7L2H4,Carry,CHOPA,PLX.inter_results.wiki.options[1]|6|options|"SSS"|true|21
$.2020-04-28.37,N7L2H4,Carry,CHOPA,PLX.inter_results.wiki.options[2]|6|options|"HHH"|true|21
$.2020-04-28.38, N5L2J4, HURT, SERRA, PZT.inter_results.inter_mark|4|inter_mark|"MARI"|false|21
$.2020-04-28.38, N5L2J4, HURT, SERRA, PZT.inter_results.down|4|down|"250"|false|21
$.2020-04-28.38, N5L2J4, HURT, SERRA, PZT.inter_results.up|4|up|"1250"|false|21
```

You can then parse the json path to get the values you want:
[image]

I split the path by "." to get the field "37,N7L2H4,Carry,CHOPA,PLX", then split the result again on "," and get the first value.
`tJSONDocOpen` allows you to initialize your json file, it acts as a connection. You then select it in `tJSONDocTraverseFields`.

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim for your help. But i checked on Talend Studio 7.1 and i don't have this component, how i get tJSONDocOpen and tJSONDocTraverseFields components?
Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, these are Talend Exchange components, developed by the community, so you have to download them from the link I posted, and install them in your studio. Unzip them in a folder on your disk, and then go to Window > Preferences > Talend, and set that folder as the user components folder.

Comment: Thank you a lot Ibrahim

Comment: Hi Ibrahim,
I have some problems when i want to deploy this in Jenkins and execute on Talend administration center..Have u please some suggestions about this? Thx